When using pywinpty, sometimes there is no output after entering the command
I try to simulate cmd.exe in python using pywinpty module, but after entering the command several times, I get no output
here's my script:
import threading
from winpty import PtyProcess

def read_output(proc):
    while proc.isalive():
        output = proc.read()
        print(output, end="")

proc = PtyProcess.spawn("cmd.exe")

thread = threading.Thread(target=read_output, args=(proc,))
thread.start()

while True:
    command = input()

    proc.write(command + "\r\n")

my terminal output:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3374]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\vIIr>echo a
echo a
a
C:\Users\vIIr>echo a
echo a
a
C:\Users\vIIr>echo a
echo a
a
C:\Users\vIIr>echo a
echo a
C:\Users\vIIr>
In this case, I execute the command echo a 3 times, but there's no output a after the first three commands.
